# Como precargar todas las imagenes del sitio web inmediatamente despues de entrar en Angular 7

Tags: javascript, angular7

Como precargar todas las imágenes del sitio web inmediatamente después de entrar en Angular 7. Para que después cuando navegue por el sitio. Pueda acceder a ellas rápidamente y no demoren en cargar.

Comment: Buenas, en primer lugar bienvenida, te recomiendo realizar el https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour para aprender como preguntar. Y añadir el codigo en el cual deseas ayuda tambien es indispensable para ponernos en situacion y poderte ayudar! un saludo

Comment: Cuando hablas de "entrar en Angular 7", ¿a qué te refieres exactamente? ¿A entrar en la página web que has desarrollado en Angular? ¿O a que Angular precargue el contenido de las imágenes dentro del bundle y se distribuyan junto con el código en un único archivo? En ese último caso necesitarás hacer uso de webpack y, por ejemplo, leer esta otra pregunta: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34436961/loading-ng-src-images-with-webpack